# fopen() and command line arguments

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that will read the first character in a text file. If I use `./a.out myfile.txt` it works as intended but if I use `./a.out <myfile.txt` I get `Segmentation fault: 11`. The reason why I'm trying to include the `<`is because this what is in the spec of the assignment. The below code is just a simplified example that i've made that has the same issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int func(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *fp;
    int test = 0;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%i", &test);
    printf( "current file: %s \n", argv[1]);


}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    func(argc, argv);   
}
```

Is there any way I can get it to accept the argument as `<myfile.txt`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, nor should you try. Files redirected this way will appear at `stdin` and you should use that instead (hint: check `argc`).

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how to use `stdin`. Can you you provide an example?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a file if specified, but otherwise stdin, use something like:

```
if (argc > 1)
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
else
    fp = stdin;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your command `./a.out <myfile` you redirect stdin to `myfile`. This means reading from stdin is actually reading from `myfile`. So, in this case your `argc == 1`, so `argv[1]` you use to open is `NULL` (see `main` spec on its arguments). `fopen` crashes when uses `NULL` name.

You may do your utility in another way: always read `stdin`. When you need file to input do  like this: `cat myfile | ./a.out`. This is very nice approach and worth considering.